# Sqlite.net doesn't create attributes of Sqlite.net Extension

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net-extensions, sqlite.net

My problem is that if I want to create two tables with a `[OneToMany]` relationship between these two.

```
public class Order : BusinessEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Title{ get; set;}

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Location{ get; set; }


    public DateTime OrderGenerated{ get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations=CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<OrderPos> Positions{ get; set; }
}

[Table("OrderPos")]
public class OrderPos : BusinessEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Order)), ManyToOne]
    public Guid OrderId{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string MaterialNr{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string State{ get; set; }

    public int Amount{ get; set; }

}
```

The table OrderPos was created without the foreignkey and so I get an exception at the `InsertOrUpdateAllWithChildren` method.

Should I use another derived class of `SqliteConnection`?

Best Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ManyToOne` attribute in the foreign ket, you would only use this if you want to load the inverse relationship, i.e. the Order object.

Replace this:

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(Order)), ManyToOne]
public Guid OrderId{ get; set; }
```

With this:

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(Order))]
public Guid OrderId{ get; set; }
```

Also I don't think Sqlite supports Guids (or it will treat as text and performance will be bad), try using int and AutoIncrement.

Otherwise it looks fine.

Ref: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions